# swift 3 how to make default UIActivityIndicatorView look like spinner of UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview, uirefreshcontrol

The default UIRefreshControl looks like this:

[image: default UIRefreshControl]

Then I want to create a UIActivityIndicatorView like that.
Right now I tried changing the color and make it bigger, but it looks like this:

[image: edited UIActivityIndicatorView]

Noticed the second one is fatter than the first one.

Comment: you should use a custom spinner

Comment: I just want to copy spinner of default UIRefreshControl =/

Comment: Did you try to change the `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle` ?